# filtrado de texto en tiempo real

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Lo que sucede es que actualmente mi filtro busca por una palabra y necesito que busque por textos de mas de una palabra y no se como hacerlo

```
     Txtbuscar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String texto = Txtbuscar.getText().toString().trim();
            //Filtra a medida que se va escribiendo el texto
            // Filtra los clientes según el texto ingresado
            if (clientesAdapter != null) {
                clientesAdapter.getFilter().filter(texto);
                // Resetea la selección del Spinner
                ClienteAfectado.setSelection(0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });
```

no se que me puede faltar :s, le hice debug al tema y segun andorid studio la variable texto esta tomando todo el texto aun que sean 2 palabras, pero aun asi no me llena mi spinner con los resultados, basicamente dice que no existen.